# Axios equivalent of curl

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, curl, axios

What is the (nodeJS) axios equivalent of:

```
curl --location --request POST '<URL>' \
--header 'API-Authorization: <KEY>' \
--form 'quantity=1' \
--form 'offset=0'
```

Tried:

```
const FormData = require('form-data')
const data = new FormData()
data.append('quantity', '1')
data.append('offset', '0')

axios({
  url: <URL>,
  method: 'POST',
  data,
  headers: {
    'API-Authorization': <KEY>
  }
})
```

But the server gives 500

Comment: There's probably a user-agent string or some other headers getting set.

Answer (score 2):

The NodeJS equivalent of your CURL request code should be something like this:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const qs = require('qs');

let data = qs.stringify({ 'quantity': '1', 'offset': '0'});
let config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://someurl.com',
    headers: { 
        'API-Authorization': '<key>', 
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    data : data
};

axios(config)
.then((response) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

What you need for this is the `qs` (QueryString) package, simply install it by `npm install qs`. I got this output simply by generating the request in Postman.

[image]